# Unable to process Timeseries data in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have timeseries data eg: 2018-10-12 01:25:37 and extracted date(2018-10-12) and time(1:25:37) from timestamp. Now requirement is to filter the time values based on a particular condition(eg:filter the time value with another bag's atom, which contains time data(hh:mm:ss)). The PIG has no 'TIME' datatype for time(hh:mm:ss) type data.
What datatype is required to load 'time' data values in PIG?

Answer (score 0):

To extract date (year, month,hr's, minutes etc). used these function

**For year:** `GetYear()`

**For month:** `GetMonth()`

**For day:** `GetDay()`

**For hour:** `GetHour()`

**For minute:** `GetMinute()`

```
date.txt
2018-10-12 11:15:43
2018-10-12 12:25:12
A = load 'date.txt' as (in:chararray);
B = foreach A generate ToDate(in,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as (dt:DateTime);
C = foreach B {
      year = GetYear(dt);
      month = GetMonth(dt);
      day = GetDay(dt);
      hour = GetHour(dt);
      minute = GetMinute(dt);
    //finally you can concatenate year month and day or hour, time using CONCAT function
};
```

Comment: I have concatenated hh, mm,ss but the main problem is, I have two datasets: A = hh:mm:ss , B= hh:mm:ss. Now I want to filter data following A>B. Here the filtration is not happening because these A and B datatypes are chararray. How can I filter this?